# Performance penalty when Generic.List<T>.Add is the last statement in a function and tailcall optimization is on

Tags: .net, f#, cil

I've run into a strange performance penalty that I've boiled down to this code:

```
[<Struct>]
type Vector3(x: float32, y: float32, z: float32) =
  member this.X = x
  member this.Y = y
  member this.Z = z

type Data(n: int) =   
  let positions = System.Collections.Generic.List<Vector3>()
  let add j = positions.Add (Vector3(j, j, j))
  let add1 j = positions.Add (Vector3(j, j, j)); ()
  member this.UseAdd () = for i = 1 to n do add (float32 i)
  member this.UseAdd1 () = for i = 1 to n do add1 (float32 i)

let timeIt name (f: unit -> unit) = 
  let timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
  f ()
  printfn "%s: %ims" name (int timer.ElapsedMilliseconds)

let test () =
  for i = 1 to 3 do timeIt "ADD" (fun () -> Data(1000000).UseAdd())
  for i = 1 to 3 do timeIt "ADD1" (fun () -> Data(1000000).UseAdd1())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  test ()
  0
```

The difference between `add` and `add1` is the extra `()` at the end.

When I build it as x64 Release build using F# 3.1 on .NET 4.5.1 I get this output:

```
ADD: 461ms
ADD: 457ms
ADD: 450ms
ADD1: 25ms
ADD1: 26ms
ADD1: 16ms
```

Since the type of `List<T>.Add` is `T -> unit` I would expect that `add` and `add1` should behave identically.

Using ILdasm I've found that `add` compiles to (including only the relevant part)

```
IL_000a:  newobj     instance void Program/Vector3::.ctor(float32,
                                                          float32,
                                                          float32)
IL_000f:  tail.
IL_0011:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<valuetype Program/Vector3>::Add(!0)
```

while `add1` into

```
IL_000a:  newobj     instance void Program/Vector3::.ctor(float32,
                                                          float32,
                                                          float32)
IL_000f:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<valuetype Program/Vector3>::Add(!0)
```

i.e. without the "tail call". So when I turn off tail call optimization, both `add` and `add1` run at the same speed.

Why does the `tail.` instruction cause the function call to be that much slower? Also, is this a bug or a feature?

---

EDIT: This is the original code here I noticed this behavior. When the `true` value at the end is dropped, it exhibits the same performance drop as the code above.

```
let makeAtom (ctx: CleanCifContext) (element: CleanCifAtomSiteElement) = 
  let residue = getResidue ctx element

  let position =
    Vector3(float32 (element.PositionX.ValueOrFail()), float32 (element.PositionY.ValueOrFail()), float32 (element.PositionZ.ValueOrFail()))
  let atom = 
    CifAtom(id = ctx.Atoms.Count, element = element.ElementSymbol.ValueOrFail(),
            residue = residue, serialNumber = element.Id.ValueOrFail(), 
            name = element.Name.ValueOrFail(), authName = element.AuthName.Value(), altLoc = element.AltLoc.Value(),
            occupancy = float32 (element.Occupancy.ValueOrFail()), tempFactor = float32 (element.TempFactor.ValueOrFail()))

  ctx.Atoms.Add atom
  ctx.Positions.Add position
  true
```

Comment: Interesting, it only occurs in .NET 4+, and the discrepancy is way smaller on x86 or when using other data types in the `List`.

Comment: @DaxFohl Yes, I've noticed that it's lower on x86 as well. But I need my code to be 64-bit so that's why I've included that data.

Comment: Did you run it on RyuJIT or on regular old-time JIT? The article that you linked seems to be related to the old one.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The old one. It is very well possible that it might be fixed in the new JIT.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured out where the problem is and why it is my misunderstanding of the problem rather than bug in the F# compiler or .NET.

The code

```
let add j = positions.Add (Vector3(j, j, j))
```

means roughly "call `List<T>.Add` from the tailcall position on the value `Vector3(j, j, j)`" while

```
let add1 j = positions.Add (Vector3(j, j, j)); ()
```

means "call `List<T>.Add` on the value `Vector3(j, j, j)` and then return `unit`".

Type-wise, there is no difference as `List<T>.Add` returns `unit` so I incorrectly assumed `positions.Add` would get called and then `add` would return the value `unit` which is the return value of `List<T>.Add`. However, as stated at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx, the JIT needs to perform some "stack magic" when the arguments of the tail-called function are non-trivial. And this is where the performance gap comes from. The difference is very subtle, but it is there.