# What is the purpose of the extra ldnull and tail. in F# implementation vs C#?

Tags: c#, f#, tail-recursion, cil, tail-call-optimization

The following C# function:

```
T ResultOfFunc<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    return f();
}
```

compiles unsurprisingly to this:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  callvirt    05 00 00 0A 
IL_0006:  ret
```

But the equivalent F# function:

```
let resultOfFunc func = func()
```

compiles to this:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldnull      
IL_0003:  tail.       
IL_0005:  callvirt    04 00 00 0A 
IL_000A:  ret
```

(Both are in release mode). There's an extra nop at the beginning which I'm not too curious about, but the interesting thing is the extra `ldnull` and `tail.` instructions.

My guess (probably wrong) is that `ldnull` is necessary in case the function is `void` so it still returns something (`unit`), but that doesn't explain what is the purpose of the `tail.` instruction. And what happens if the function does push something on the stack, isn't it stuck with an extra null that doesn't get popped?

Comment: I suspect that in this case the function has been convertyed to a tail call - the new function gets to use the stack space of the old one

Comment: Note that this is likely to cause a performance pessimization, see this question: [Performance penalty when Generic.List<T>.Add is the the last statement in a function and tailcall optimization is on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28649422/636019)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C# and F# versions have an important distinction: C# function doesn't have any parameters, but F# version has one parameter of type `unit`. That `unit` value is what shows up as `ldnull` (because `null` is being used as representation of the only `unit` value, `()`).

If you were to translate the second function to C#, it would look like this:

```
T ResultOfFunc<T>( Func<Unit, T> f ) {
   return f( null );
}
```

As for the `.tail` instruction - that is so called "tail call optimization".
During a regular function call, a return address gets pushed on the stack (the CPU stack) and then the function is called. When the function is done, it executes the "return" instruction, which pops the return address off the stack and transfers control there.
However, when function `A` calls function `B`, and then immediately returns function `B`'s return value, without doing anything else, the CPU can skip pushing the extra return address on the stack, and perform a "*jump*" to `B` instead of a "*call*". That way, when `B` executes the "return" instruction, the CPU will pop return address from the stack, and that address will point not to `A`, but to whoever called `A` in the first place.
Another way to think about it is: function `A` calls function `B` not *before* returning, but *instead of* returning, and thus delegates the honor of returning to `B`.

So in effect, this magic technique allows us to make a call *without consuming a spot on the stack*, which means that you can perform arbitrarily many such calls without risking stack overflow. This is very important in functional programming, because it allows to efficiently implement recursive algorithms.

It is called "tail call", because call to `B` happens, so to say, *at the tail* of `A`.